# EditText how to activate copy/paste popup without any actionbar?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-theme, android-styles

I m under delphi and i use the android framework to create an edit. When i set the theme to **Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar** then i can select some text in my EditText and i have a popup with "select all/cut/copy/paste/etc" like you can see on the picture below.

However, when i select **Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar** or **Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar** then i **can't select** any text in my EditText (i have no right or left text selection handles) and off course i don't have any copy/paste popup

Is their any way to have this copy/paste popup on Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar ?

[image]
Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar

[image]
Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar

[image]
Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

**NOTE 1:**

When i move the screen to the horizontal then the edittext take all the available space, and then i can see my right and left text selection handles like on the picture below, but i think it's because theme swap to **Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar** when i move the screen to the horizontal but i m not sure :

[image]

**NOTE 2**:

On my editText, when i do **setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback**(new Callback() {}) then the Callback is never called :( this is not normal i think ? What in the editText can forbid the callback ?

**NOTE 2**:

I can select text in all theme (but i can't copy it off course), but except in Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar i can't see the right and left text selection handle.

**NOTE 3**:

Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar show the right and left text selection handle only on some phones like the samsung galaxy. On some other it's didn't work.

**NOTE 4**:

i found partially the source of the problem! it's because i create my view via the WindowManager.addView(view, layout_params) and in this way startactionmodeforChild return null and this forbid the actionbar and the text selection handles to be show. Now if i do something like this in my edittext :

```
@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    Activity host = (Activity) this.getContext();    
    return host.getWindow().getDecorView().startActionMode(callback); 
}
```

then i can see the right and left text action handles (but not on marshmallow, it's work only on lollipop this i don't know why). My problem now is that the actionbar is showed, but it's showed empty :( nothing is draw inside (but i can see that the cut/copy/past control are inside in the dump view hierarchie). So now i m not looking for a way to replace this actionbar by a popup menu instead (like on the picture Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar). Any idea ?

Comment: This thread is old. Anyway a working example: http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-floating-context-menu.htm

Comment: @boctulus Link is broken, here the "wayback" one https://web.archive.org/web/20170602162118/http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-floating-context-menu.htm

Answer (score 5):

add following in your activity

```
ActionMode mActionMode;
```

and you have to create an ActionMondeCallback interface

```
class ActionBarCallback implements ActionMode.Callback
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.item_delete)
            {
                tv.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"option deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    }
```

where contextual_menu.xml is as follows with required icons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.letschat"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_share"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Now Enable your Contextual ActionBar(CAB) As follows as for example here am are enabling on long click of a textview

```
yourtextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mActionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallback());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

then you have to write your own action on click on each action event on CAB.

~**Bounty Hunter**
[More details here](https://dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab)

Comment: @Loki, did this helped?

Comment: Thanks Loki, the best part about this question, my office team of 5 discussed in this topic and I googled a lot and at last I found this.

Comment: if you like bounty i start another on something similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561133/why-the-floating-actionbar-copy-paste-is-under-my-edittext :)

Answer (score 4):

For API level 11 or above then you can stop copy,paste,cut and custom context menus from appearing by.

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Returning false from onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions).

**Solution: Override isSuggestionsEnabled and canPaste in EditText.**

For the quick solution, copy the class below - this class overrides the EditText class, and blocks all events accordingly.

For the gritty details, keep reading.

The solution lies in preventing PASTE/REPLACE menu from appearing in the show() method of the (non-documented) android.widget.Editor class. Before the menu appears, a check is done to if (!canPaste && !canSuggest) return;. The two methods that are used as the basis to set these variables are both in the EditText class:

`isSuggestionsEnabled()` is public, and may thus be overridden.
`canPaste()` is not, and thus must be hidden by introducing a function of the same name in the derived class.
So incorporating these updates into a class that also has the `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`, and the disabled long-click, here is the full class to prevent all editing (but still display the text selection handler) for controlling the cursor:

```
package com.cjbs.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 *  This is a thin veneer over EditText, with copy/paste/spell-check removed.
 */
public class NoMenuEditText extends EditText

{
    private final Context context;

    /** This is a replacement method for the base TextView class' method of the same name. This 
     * method is used in hidden class android.widget.Editor to determine whether the PASTE/REPLACE popup
     * appears when triggered from the text insertion handle. Returning false forces this window
     * to never appear.
     * @return false
     */
    boolean canPaste()
    {
       return false;
    }

    /** This is a replacement method for the base TextView class' method of the same name. This method
     * is used in hidden class android.widget.Editor to determine whether the PASTE/REPLACE popup
     * appears when triggered from the text insertion handle. Returning false forces this window
     * to never appear.
     * @return false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isSuggestionsEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public NoMenuEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public NoMenuEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public NoMenuEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionModeCallbackInterceptor());
        this.setLongClickable(false);
    }


    /**
     * Prevents the action bar (top horizontal bar with cut, copy, paste, etc.) from appearing
     * by intercepting the callback that would cause it to be created, and returning false.
     */
    private class ActionModeCallbackInterceptor implements ActionMode.Callback
    {
        private final String TAG = NoMenuEditText.class.getSimpleName();

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) { return false; }
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! Your suggestion is working, however i don't want to remove the cut/copy/past/ in opposite i want to show it ! but i understand why it's was not showing, it's because startactionmodeforChild return null ! now i override startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)  with ActionMode = MyActivity.startActionMode(callback); and it's work (partially). it's work partially because the actionbar is shown but it's not drawed :( i don't understand why

Comment: Lemme know if I get bounty. Hahaha

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by lemme ?

Comment: Its British accent "lemme" = "let me"

Comment: W4R10CK you answer was very good, but unfortunatly it's the total opposite of what i want to achieve (i want to show the action bar and you explain me how to hide it)

Comment: @loki try setting `false` to `true`.

Comment: yes when i set false to true, i can see the text selection handle but not the status bar :( actually i try to create my action bar myself with Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this.getContext()); and set it to the activity like MyActivity.setActionBar(toolbar); ... it's didn't work too my toolbar is not use as an action bar :(

Comment: If you want a custom bar, I just posted a answer from a link. Please follow and let me know.

Comment: @loki the below answer is for custom Actionbar, just like what we get when copy paste. Try to work on it .

Answer (score 2):

Try to use theme **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**.
Also set `android:textIsSelectable="true"` on your EditText in xml file.

Comment: when i try to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar i receive: *No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar').

Comment: If possible, kindly help herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858810/clipboard-shows-a-different-label-especially-on-samsung-android-phone