# How to change the z-order of window added via WindowManager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-layoutparams

Is it possible to specify the z-order of each window ? in the image below each editText are in their own window added via WindowManager. as you can see i have a z-order problem

[image]

like you see on the picture, **the last window added** seam to take the higher z-order. So the only way out i find to put a window at the higher z-order is to remove the view from windowManager and then immediately add it again. It's not very optimal solution, because visually the view disappear and reappear on the screen

Comment: Have u try to add the views into WindowManager in the inversed order ?

Comment: It seems to me that the popup's window is added to the attached EditText' windows.

Comment: yes, the popup's window is added to the attached editText, but the problem is that other window have an higher z-order, so i must find a way (on focusing) to set the z-order of the window containing the EditText to be the highest

Comment: > set the z-order of the window containing the EditText to be the highest

Changing the window type of the Window `LayoutParams` will solve that ?

Comment: you can not change the window type when the window is already added :( you must first remove it, and then add it back again and this cause an ugly flick (edit disappear and reappear) :(

Comment: U can use `WindowManager.updateViewLayout` to change the window type ?

Comment: no, not when the view is already added to the windowManager :( because else i have a error "try to update the window type of an already added window"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145574/discussion-between-tin-tran-and-loki).