# How to get the window instance from a view?

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-window

i add a view in the windowManager via `mWindowManager.addview()`. Now i would like to know if it's possible to get the `window` instance. their is `myView.getWindowID()` and `myView.getWindowToken()` but i can't find a way to retrieve from it the window instance

Answer (score 7):

If your `View` has been attached to `Activity`, you can do like this.

```
View view; // your view
if (view.getContext() instanceof Activity) {
    Window window = ((Activity) view.getContext()).getWindow();
}
```

After API 19, there is a convenient method to check, `view.isAttachedToWindow()`

Comment: yes thanks, but without too much surprise, you code gave me the window of the app instead of the window where the view sit in :( ie the window created by the windowManager when we call the method addView

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a `window` instance from `View` or `WindowManager`.
But you can get the `Display` to which the View's `window` is been attached by calling this method   `myView.getDisplay()`

Edited -you can use `View.bringToFront();` or `View.bringChildToFront(View child);` to reorder the z-index of views.

Comment: Thanks Vishnu ... I wondering **why** it's not possible to retrieve the window instance? Actually i need it because i would like to see if it's possible to change it's z-order (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231597/how-work-the-z-order-of-view-added-via-windowmanager)

Comment: the z-order is recently added view addView() is on top. so if you remove a view and again call addView() on that same view it comes to top.

Another way is to have single FrameLayout added to window manager and then add other views to this framelayout so that you manipulate the z-ordering of views inside FrameLayout

Comment: thanks vishnu, seam you understand. yes the z-order of the recently added view (via windowmanager) is on the top, however removing it to add it back make the view visually disappear and reappear that is not very convenient :(

Comment: you can use View.bringToFront();  or  View.bringchildToFront(View child); to reorder the z-index

Answer (score -1):

**myView.getDisplay()**
you can use this method to display the View.

Comment: thanks mageNative, but what i can do with getDisplay ?