# How Do I Determine if a View is in a Secure Window?

Tags: android

Given a `View`, how can I determine if that `View` is being shown in a `Window` that has `FLAG_SECURE`?

In the simple case, where the `View` is shown directly in the window for an `Activity`, we can [get that `Window`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44256696/115145), then call `getAttributes().flags` and see if those flags include `FLAG_SECURE`.

However:

- That may not be accurate if the `View` is being shown in some child window of the activity (the activity might have a secure window but the child window might not be secure)
- It will not work for non-activity windows (e.g., a `Service` and `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`)

Is there a technique that can handle those edge cases as well?

Comment: you might be looking for attribute flag `0x20000` (`FLAG_SECURE`). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928313/how-to-query-flag-secure-from-current-apk-screen-via-command-line) is similar, but it's `adb shell dumpsys`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: I do not know how to get to those flags from a `View`, other than by trying to look at the `Activity` associated with that `View`. That misses the edge cases I mention in the bullets.

Comment: what they all have in common is a parent `Window`; even something displayed in a child-window has a parent `Window`. So one would need to find the immediate parent `Window` of a `View`.

Comment: @CommonsWare If it's something important to be shown on screen. Why we cannot use custom toast with `View`, which would be shown on the secure `Window`, and can work within context only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `View.AttachInfo`, which contains all relevant window information, only provides access to the window token, session and id. The window itself is nowhere referenced within `View`.

But as the flag itself is defined as [`Display.FLAG_SECURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE), you would want to look for the display flags. You can easily access these with [`View.getDisplay()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDisplay()).

> Gets the logical display to which the view's window has been attached.

The [`Display.getFlags()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getFlags()) itself should contain the `FLAG_SECURE`.

Comment: Note that `getDisplay()` only works sometime after `onCreate()` of the activity returns. `getDisplay()` will return `null` from inside of `onCreate()`. That could pose some problems in some situations, but the bulk of the time this approach should work. Thanks!