# System generated Copy - Paste popup option cant show in popup window Android

Tags: android, mobile, android-edittext, mobile-application, android-7.0-nougat

I am showing one popup window and in that popup window there is one Edit Text and when i am doing Long press on Edit Text so at that copy-paste popup doesn't show me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39532052/4148757

Comment: @ bhaskar this one test create one demo and check this but its wont work in my phone ...i have OnePlus 3 with 7.1 Nougat

Comment: Have you got any solution?